# Python pexpect cannot het control back from the child after child.read()

Tags: python, user-interface, pexpect

I am new to Python, and I usually work with C and Matlab. The reason for jumping to Python is that I am creating a GUI for an interactive program written in C.

I am using **pexpect** to interact with the C-code (which runs in a terminal on Mac/ Linux). Here is the code snippet for that

```
child = pexpect.spawn("./eva abcd.txt")
```

#(eva is a compiled C code and abcd.txt is the data    file which is loaded in the C code, this step is successful)

```
child.expect("Enter command: ")
child.sendline("read")
child.sendline("g ")

#(everything is fine until this line)
output = child.read()
```

The output of the C-code is basically in a graphics window (Geomview, I guess). and doing child.read() displays the graphics perfectly. But the control of the Python script gets stuck in the child application and I cannot do any further **child.sendline()** after I do **child.read()**.
Is there any way to pass the control back to the Python script? I was thinking if there is some way to pass control back to the Python script once the child.read() reaches the end of file.

I want to be able to do child.read() and child.sendline() multiple times so as to get a real-time graphical window.

I don't know if my question makes any sense. I would be very grateful if I could get some suggestions to deal with this problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, when you use `read()` without a range of bytes to look at, it will read everything in the buffer until it hits the `EOF`, and then close the child (*and the app*) implicitly, without an explicit `child.close()`:

`read(size=-1)` from [the pexpect.spawnbase class](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/pexpect/spawnbase.html):

```
This reads at most "size" bytes from the file (less if the read hits EOF before obtaining size bytes). If the size argument is negative or omitted, read all data until EOF is reached. The bytes are returned as a string object. An empty string is returned when EOF is encountered immediately.
```

That is why you cannot do any further `child.sendline()`; the app has closed.

Using `sendline` with `expect` may be your best bet. I'm not familiar with Geomview, so I used a looped Matplotlib plot as an example, since it displays the plot in a graphics window. Run `plot_control.py` to interact with `plotter.py`:

> **NOTE** - Using Python 3.8.10 on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

```
"""plotter.py"""
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

while True:
    x = []
    y = []
    n = 0
    while n <= 0:
        n = int(input("Enter number of values: "))

    for i in range(0, n):
        v = float(input("Enter X value {0}: ".format(i)))
        x.append(v)
    print(x)

    for i in range(0, n):
        v = float(input("Enter Y value {0}: ".format(i)))
        y.append(v)
    print(y)

    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.show()
    plt.close()
    while True:
        replot = input("Would you like to plot again (y/n): ")
        if replot.lower().startswith("y"):
            break
        elif replot.lower().startswith("n"):
            print("Script complete. Have a nice day.")
            exit()
```

---

```
"""plot_control.py"""
import pexpect


def plot(child, x, y, replot="No"):
    """Interacts with plotter.py to create plots.
    
    :param pexpect.spawn child: The running instance of the child application.
    :param list x: The X-axis values.
    :param list y: The Y-axis values; must be the same size as x.
    :param str replot: Tells the child to standby to replot. Default value is No.
    :return: None
    :rtype: None
    """
    child.expect_exact("Enter number of values:")
    child.sendline(str(len(x)))
    for index, v in enumerate(x):
        child.expect_exact("Enter X value {0}:".format(index))
        child.sendline(str(v))
    for index, v in enumerate(y):
        child.expect_exact("Enter Y value {0}:".format(index))
        child.sendline(str(v))
    child.expect_exact("Would you like to plot again (y/n): ", timeout=-1)
    child.sendline(replot)


child = pexpect.spawn("python3 plotter.py")
plot(child, [2, 4, 8, 10, ], [3, 2.9, 2.9, 3, ], "Yes")
plot(child, [1, 2, 3, ], [4, 1, 2, ], "No")
child.close()
```

`plot_control.py` will send the first set of inputs to `plotter.py`. After a few seconds, the first plot will appear. Close it, and `plot_control.py` will send the next set of inputs to the ***still-living child***: the next plot will appear or you will receive a notification it is ready. Once you close the second plot, the child will close and the application will exit.

BTW, you can use `child.before`, `child.after`, and `child.buffer` to look at `plot.py` output. Good luck with your code!